# curl on command prompt giving could not resolve localhost

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to run some elastic commands through curl.

On command prompt, when I type:

- `curl www.google.com`: it works fine
- `curl localhost:9200`: elastic search hosted here, works fine

But, the command:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary "@accounts.json"`
```

Gives me error: `Could not resolve host: 'localhost`

Below is snapshot.[image: error in window cmd]

Can someone suggest me how to correct this? Or if somehow I can use postman or some other http client to run this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary`

Answer (score 8):

Specify the protocol and change the quotes:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@accounts.json"
```

Comment: Perfect, I just needed to change the quotes on mine.  Why does double quotes work and single quotes don't?

Answer (score 2):

There are good answers here, but they don't explain *why*. The problem is that the Windows command shell does not recognize the single quote as a quote character (like Linux/Mac command shells do). Thus, cmd interprets `'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty'` literally, passing that string to curl -- including the single quote characters. Curl then uses everything before the colon as the host name, which is is `'localhost`, and that's exactly the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes instead. For example:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty"
```